# Cordova Unable to start geolocation service

Tags: cordova, geolocation, cordova-2.0.0

In my phonegap application I am getting an error code 2, with the message "Can't start the geolocation service". 
I followed the geolocation doc, and I have the permission in the AndroidManifest.xml and in res/xml/config.xml. 
 
Android 4, Cordova 2 running using cordova/emulate and cordova/debug.

Comment: Did you enabled geolocation in Android settings?

Comment: Settings -> Location and Security -> Use GPS satellites and Use wireless networks.

Comment: I don't have location and security, but I have "Location Services" and I enabled both options , picture: http://i46.tinypic.com/yfj8p.jpg

Comment: btw, I saw that using "enableHighAccuracy" on phonegap should be able to fix that on the emulators, but it dosen't helps..